# Unknown <uses-permission android:name="TASKS"/> in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am opening an old Android Project and between the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml I found this line:     `<uses-permission android:name="TASKS"/>` but I can't recall what is the use for and sadly I can't find any documentation either.

Comment: That permission is not from the Android SDK.

Comment: What would that be then?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.